# Differential Equation Where coefficients have common factor

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Take the ODE $a_2(x)y''(x) + a_1(x)y'(x) + a_0(x)y(x) = L_{a}[y(x)]= 0$ and suppose the there is a common multiple of of $(x-1)$ in all the coefficients s.t. 
$(x-1)[b_2(x)y''(x) + b_1(x)y'(x) + b_0(x)y(x)] = (x-1)L_b[y(x)]= 0$.

If I solve $L_b[y(x)]= 0$, what does this mean about the solutions to $L_a[y(x)]= 0$?

Comment: Just a rough guess, if $L_b$ is uniquely solvable, then the solutions are almost the same, but it can "jump" at $x=1$.
If you require your solution to be twice cont. differentiable, then the past already determines the value and derivatives of $y_b$ at $x=1$ and both solutions will be equal. But if you allow weaker solutions, then the jump might appear.
Therefore, do you have any particular solutions spaces in mind?  ($C^2$?)